# "There was only one I didn't" vs "only one I didn't"

Tags: sentence-construction

> There was only one thing I didn't dare to tell him.
>
> Only one thing I didn't dare to tell him.

Are both sentences the same? If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the first sentence; it's complete and correct grammatically. However, the second one is incomplete. It should be like "Only one thing I didn't dare to tell him was that I was badly in need of money".